# Avoiding Replay Attacks while Using FIDO2's HMAC Secret to Encrypt Data

Tags: fido2

[FIDO2's HMAC Secret extension](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-v2.1-rd-20201208/fido-client-to-authenticator-protocol-v2.1-rd-20201208.html#sctn-hmac-secret-extension) generates a symmetric secret that can be used to encrypt and decrypt data. HMAC secret's output is based on

`output1: HMAC-SHA-256(CredRandom, salt1)`

Where `salt1` is from the platform and `CredRandom` is generated and kept secret by the authenticator. After platform encrypts some data using `output1`, the next time platform needs the same key to decrypt data, it needs to send the same `salt1`, and then presumably the authenticator will send the same response back.

Q: how does the platform avoid a middleman recording the response from the authenticator, and replay it to the platform to decrypt data bypassing the authenticator?